# A clock has an hour, minute, and second hand. Which of the three hands is most likely to bisect the angle created by the other two?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Imagine a three-handed clock with an hour ($h$), minute ($m$), and second ($s$) hand. Line $s$ moves at $6$ degrees per second, line *m* moves at $1/10$ of a degree per second, and line *h* moves at $1/120$ of a degree per second. Which of the three hands is the most likely to bisect the angle that the other two create at any given time?
>
> a) $\overline s$ bisects $\angle hm$
>
> b) $\overline m$ bisects $\angle hs$
>
> c) $\overline h$ bisects $\angle sm$
>
> Justify.

To approach this problem, I decided to use a polar graph in degree format. I utilized this type of graph to create a trigonometrical definition of bisection that would work for this problem.

> Let $a_1$ and $b_1$ be $\mathbb R$ where:
>
> $0\leq\mathbb R\leq360$
>
> $a_1\neq b_1$
>
> On any polar graph, the line $l$ that passes through a certain degree $k$ can be defined as follows:
>
> $$l=\frac{\left(\sin(k)-\frac{\sin(k)}{\Bbb R}\right)}{\left(\cos(k)-\frac{\cos(k)}{\Bbb R}\right)}$$
>
> Where $\Bbb R \neq 0,1$
>
> Therefore, the line $a_2$ that passes through $a_1$ can be defined as:
>
> $$a_2=\frac{\left(\sin(a_1)-\frac{\sin(a_1)}{\Bbb R}\right)}{\left(\cos(a_1)-\frac{\cos(a_1)}{\Bbb R}\right)}$$
>
> Likewise, the line $b_2$ that passes through $b_1$ can be defined as:
>
> $$b_2=\frac{\left(\sin(b_1)-\frac{\sin(b_1)}{\Bbb R}\right)}{\left(\cos(b_1)-\frac{\cos(b_1)}{\Bbb R}\right)}$$
>
> The angle that is created through the bisection of $a_1$ and $b_1$ can be defined as:
>
> $$\frac{\left(a_1+b_1\right)}{2}$$
>
> Therefore, the line $c$ that bisects the angle created by lines $a_2$ and $b_2$ is
>
> $$c=\frac{\left(\sin(\frac{\left(a_1+b_1\right)}{2})-\frac{\sin(\frac{\left(a_1+b_1\right)}{2})}{\Bbb R}\right)}{\left(\cos(\frac{\left(a_1+b_1\right)}{2})-\frac{\cos(\frac{\left(a_1+b_1\right)}{2})}{\Bbb R}\right)}$$
>
> [An interactive version of this concept can be found here. Note that two was used for $\Bbb R$.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/llt83qfoa6)

Using this knowledge, I then substituted variables $a$ and $b$ for variables $s$, $m$, and $h$. For variable $c$, I created three different variables each summarizing the three possible outcomes, and that is as far as I have gotten. [Here, you can find what I have so far regarding the problem itself. Once again, 2 was used for $\Bbb R$.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aj8oie6eur)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3396947/edit) to add clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's the same for each.

Every minute,
as the second hand makes a revolution,
it is first, before the other two hands,
next, between them,
and, finally, after them.

In each of these cases,
there will be a time in which
one of the hands
bisects the angle
formed by the other two hands.

If you allow for the cases
when the second bisects the
external angle
formed by the other two hands,
then it will bisect
twice as often.

Comment: I am still working on this myself, so I will edit my work as I make more breakthroughs. However, because you are the 2nd person to tell me that they will be the same, I am highly tempted to lean towards saying that and calling it a day

Comment: I figured it out: the second-hand bisects the other 2 the most. I'm explaining why as we speak

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

First, the probability for any of the three bisections at a given instant of time is $0$, so I don't think that can be a proper interpretation of the question.

You could ask which of the three bisections occurs with greatest frequency. Well the second hand moves fastest. In one minute it will be the third segment in any one of the bisections exactly once, so each bisection occurs once per minute.

Neither of these interpretations matches the multiple choices offered.

Comment: "You could ask which of the three bisections occurs with greatest frequency" Yeah, perhaps that was what I was going for but I just didn't understand how to word it at the time?